# Case Statement Not Assigning Value

Tags: scheme, racket, case-statement

I'm having some trouble debugging a case statement. I was hoping that the statement would assign numeric values to `note-val`, but so far it is assigning `#<void>`. I know it's something wrong with the case statement, because if I add an else clause, that value gets applied. Given a sample input of `'(((#\3 #\A) (#\4 #\B)) ((#\4 #\C)))`, what am I doing wrong here? (In regards to the case statement. I'm sure there are other errors, but I'd like to try to work those out myself if I can get this fixed.)

```
(define (calc-freqs chord)
  (let ((octave (char->int (caaar chord)))
        (note-val (case (cdaar chord)
                    [((#\B #\#) (#\C))      0]
                    [((#\C #\#) (#\D #\b))  1]
                    [((#\D))                2]
                    [((#\D #\#) (#\E #\b))  3]
                    [((#\E) (#\F #\b))      4]
                    [((#\E #\#) (#\F))      5]
                    [((#\F #\#) (#\G #\b))  6]
                    [((#\G))                7]
                    [((#\G #\#) (#\A #\b))  8]
                    [((#\A))                9]
                    [((#\A #\#) (#\B #\b)) 10]
                    [((#\B) (#\C #\b))     11])))
    (cons (* a4 (expt 2 (+ (- octave 4) (/ (- note-val 9) 12))))
          (if (pair? (cdr chord))
              (calc-freqs (cdr chord))
              '()))))
```

Oh, and `char->int` is a tiny utility function I wrote that pretty much does what it says in the name (`#\1` => `1`, and so on).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`case` does matching using `eqv?`. That means that anything other than symbols, numbers, characters, booleans, or the empty list will never match.

In your case, you were trying to match (non-empty) lists. That will never work. :-( (Neither will matching strings or vectors work.)

Comment: Well, shit. Thanks for the heads up. Do you know of another way to go about this, or am I stuck using an ugly step-ladder of nested `if`s?

Comment: @Andrew: You can use `cond`. :-)

Answer (score 3):

To add to the prior answer (in a way that allows me to add code): if you're using Racket, you might be interested in the "match" form:

```
#lang racket

(require rackunit)

(define (pitchclass->half-steps pitchclass)
  (match pitchclass
    [(or "B#" "C")   0]
    [(or "C#" "Db")  1]
    ["D"             2]
    [(or "D#" "Eb")  3]
    [(or "E" "Fb")   4]
    [(or "E#" "F")   5]
    [(or "F#" "Gb")  6]
    ["G"             7]
    [(or "G#" "Ab")  8]
    ["A"             9]
    [(or "A#" "Bb") 10]
    [(or "B" "Cb")  11]))

;; TEST CASES:

(check-equal? (pitchclass->half-steps "Ab") 8)
(check-equal? (pitchclass->half-steps (apply string '(#\D #\#))) 3)
```

The second test case illustrates how you might use this if you're really married to the "list-of-chars" representation.